# How to detect swipe gesture in a tiny view?

Tags: ios, uiview, uigesturerecognizer

I already know how to attach a swipe gesture to view.

Suppose I have a tiny view (0,0,5,5).When I swipe in it, the action with that gesture is not trigger. Then I debugged, I found out the tap event I attached with this view interfere the swipe. How can I make the swipe action trigger with that tiny view?

Summary, with a same view, if it's tiny -  the Tap gesture will handle the action. If it's bigger, the swipe gesture will handle it.

Comment: How in the world do you expect to be able to swipe in a 25-pixel area?  It is impossible for the human finger.

Comment: why do you want to swipe a  5*5 view? maybe there is a better way if you tell us what you need it for.

Comment: @Borrrden:Do you know the minimum length required for the user to swipe? I tested with the rec (0 0; 109.5 23), I can swift right/left but can't swift up/down. The tap gesture will handle this case.

Comment: @Hermione333: I'm writing a module that when make the view split horizontally or vertically depend on swipe left/right or up/down.

Comment: In my experience, a 32x32 area is the minimum required for the user to be able to even **tap** the view effectively, so I assume it must be at least double that.

Comment: can you add a bigger clear colored view on top of it to detect the swipe in a bigger area?